# Energy conserving Hamiltonian numerical integration

Tags: integration, reference-request, numerical-methods

I understand that a set of [ODE's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) can be solved using numerical integration methods e.g. [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method)

Now, for some Hamiltonian system, we have a set of ODEs specified by [Hamilton's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics).

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02378) discusses the advantage of a symplectic scheme that conserves the energy of the Hamiltonian system and phase space properties, something which explicit methods like Runge-Kutta do not do.

**My question is** what is the **method** for integrating Hamilton's equations in a way that conserves energy, phase-space etc? I cannot seem to find an explicit method laid out anywhere.

Comment: There is not one method - there is a whole set of methods that has this property. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator . As a concrete example: for a system of particles interacting via gravity (or any other conservative force) then the [Leap-Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) has this property. Related paper: [Construction of higher order symplectic integrators](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960190900923?via%3Dihub)

Comment: btw another good paper related to this that I recommend is ["Geometric numerical integration"](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/~gantumur/docs/down/gniverlet.pdf)